# Obtaining cropped,unskewed AND uncropped raw image when using BlinkID iOS SDK

Tags: ios, swift, microblink, blinkid

I'm trying to capture ID scan using MicroBlink BlinkID library
I need to get both:

1. processed , cropped unskewed image from front and back of the ID
2. unprocessed raw UIImage of which front picture was processed out.

`returnFullDocumentImage` and `encodeFullDocumentImage` but I'm always getting cropped images accessing those properties:

`fullDocumentFrontImage?.image`

`fullDocumentBackImage?.image`

how to get uncropped front image of the ID?

whatever I do, I get nil when trying to access: `frontCameraFrame?.image`

Answer (score 3):

Found it

I needed to set

`blinkIdCombinedRecognizer.saveCameraFrames = true`

Answer (score 3):

Yes, that’s correct! By setting saveCameraFrame to true, you can obtain frontCameraFrame, backCameraFrame, and barcodeCameraFrame.

Also, if you want to extract the face image or the signature from the document, you can do that:

```
self.blinkIdRecognizer?.result.faceImage
self.blinkIdRecognizer?.result.signatureImage
```